# Android library with generic resource

Tags: android, embedded-resource, android-resources, android-drawable

I wrote an android library for some UI utilities. I have a function that return ImageView. But, my problem is that I want that the resource of the drawable image, will be in the project that contains the library.  I will explain...

I want that the ImageView will always take the drawable with the source name: `R.drawable.ic_img_logo` (and only this name). This resource will not actually be in the library. But the project that contains the library will contains also drawable with the resource name `R.drawable.ic_img_logo`.

I know that this thing works with id (of views), you can create file call `ids.xml` and define some ids in the file that others can use them, and you will recognize them.
But how can I do this with drawables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to create a file called `drawables.xml` in the library. Then inside it write:

```
<resource>
    <item name="ic_img_logo" type="drawable" />
</resource>
```

Its make fake resource `R.drawable.ic_img_logo`. Then if the project that include the library have drawable called `ic_img_logo`. The library be able to access to this drawable, because it will be the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

If the drawable is not in the library, then it's not a resource.

An alternative would be accessing it from the assets, like this:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(path_in_assets), null);
```

Where the `path_in_assets` would be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

you have to name the file ic_img_logo